# Unable to launch Jupyter notebook "Setting up proxy to JupyterLab"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I created a VM Instance (n1-standard-8) for a project. I was using AI Platform > Workbench (Jupyter Notebook). I was able to read the data from Cloud storage and process it. After 2 months, I tried to start the notebook and clicked on 'OPEN JUPYTERLAB'. It just spins up saying "Setting up proxy to Jupyterlab".

- Environment: Kaggle Python
- Machine Type: n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30
  GB RAM)

What is the possible issue?

PS: New to Google Cloud

Comment: Can you look at Serial logs. The error normally means, VM can't register with Proxy. Check Service Account

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a new VPC without adding the DNS rules for the various notebooks endpoints.
Then, use the configured network with a new notebook instance clicking the “OPEN JUPYTERLAB” URL.

You can see more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/service-perimeter#configure-dns).

Another possible thing that could be happening if you check your logs is an error that shows this “ - Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for  project'”. This happens because you are using the non-default service account that you specified during the notebook creation. So the solution to this is to use the default service account.

Comment: did my answer help you?